# What does a white icon of a brick with a plus sign mean in the instruction booklet?

Tags: instructions

I'm putting together the LEGO Orchid from the botanicals collection. On page 26 of the instruction booklet, step 34 has a strange icon: a white 2x2 brick with a "+" (plus) symbol.

[image: icon with a white 2x2 brick and plus symbol]

There are no bricks that look anything like this piece being used in this step, and the arrow is pointing to a rod.

[image: instructions step 34]

What is this icon trying to communicate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that the part does not come in a numbered bag.

For example, see page 117 of the [instructions for set 42158 "NASA Perseverance Rover"](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/42158), which I recently built:

[image: snippet from instructions]

That's telling me to get ready the contents of numbered bag 3, plus the wheels. If I recall correctly, the wheels did *not* come in any numbered bag, but rather in either an unnumbered bag or loose in the set's cardboard box.

Then the symbol is used again in the specific instructions step in which the aforementioned parts (in my case, the wheels) are used:

[image: snippet from instructions]

The same happens with bag 4 and some flex tubes. Again, the flex tubes were **not** inside bag 4:

[image: snippet from instructions]

[image: snippet from instructions]

---

This symbol is not only used in Technic builds. For example, see [the instructions for set 60335 "Train Station"](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/60335):

[image: snippet from instructions]

---

Specifically for set 10311 "Orchid", note that the symbol also appears on page 20 of its [instructions booklet](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/10311), about what numbered bag goes next:

[image: snippet from instructions]

Comment: I never would have guessed that this was what this symbol meant, but one of these rods was indeed free floating. (The other was in bag 1, weirdly.) Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! BTW, they're not "rods", they're "axles". You've come to the place where people can be extremely nitpicky about nomenclature of parts :-P

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure what the correct term was -- not like the instruction booklet has the names written anywhere. :-/

Comment: Don't worry ;-) bricklink.com is your friend for identifying stuff given a set number.